# Why Firefox on the VM has the same capabilities of the Firefox of the host machine?

Tags: virtualbox, firefox, virtualization, plugins

I installed a virtual machine on VirtualBox. My host machine is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
My problem is that I found all the addons of Firefox of the host Ubuntu  in the Firefox browser of the guest machine.
In the guest machine, when I check the folder where the addons  are saved, I do not find anything, but from its behavior, I guessed that it has all the capabilities Firefox-hostmachine has (for example I can watch Youtube on the VM without installing an approriate addon).
How can I avoid that the addons of host machine to be used by the browser of the virtual machine ?

Comment: Which flash-player did you install on your host-machine?

Comment: I installed Adobe Flash on the host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox (and Chrom(e/ium) can sync your password, add-ons, bookmarks and more from any device to any other device. For firefox it is explained in this [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/sync-your-add-ons-another-copy-firefox). From chrome [here](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.nl/2010/12/now-available-with-google-apps-google_17.html).

You have this enabled it seems ;)

Comment: The link explains that only add-ons installed from Firefox's add-on repository are synced. How come flash-player was installed (I believe it is Adobe flash)?

Comment: I did what the picture shows on the link, and I got the result I wanted. But I do not know how the addons of the host worked on the firefox of the VM without needing to be installed.